# adjusting legend placement in plot of prc:vegan

Tags: r, plot

```
data(pyrifos)
week <- gl(11, 12, labels=c(-4, -1, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 15, 19, 24))
dose <- factor(rep(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 44, 6, 0.1, 44, 0.9, 0, 6), 11))
ditch <- gl(12, 1, length=132)
mod <- prc(pyrifos, dose, week)
plot(mod)
```

how can I control the placement of the legend in this graph? e.g. if i want it in the bottom right corner instead - for my own data (not shown) the default placement covers the data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the help for `plot.prc()`?? the `legpos` parameter is responsible for legend position

Here is you solution

```
library(vegan)
data(pyrifos)
week <- gl(11, 12, labels=c(-4, -1, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 15, 19, 24))
dose <- factor(rep(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 44, 6, 0.1, 44, 0.9, 0, 6), 11))
ditch <- gl(12, 1, length=132)
mod <- prc(pyrifos, dose, week)
plot(mod, legpos="bottomright")
```

Comment: thank you! I'm relatively new to R and did not see this in the help documentation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. But remember that `help` may be your best friend :)